# Regular expression to capture split strings by numbers, including those with these symbols? (Why doesn't this expression work?)

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string by its digits, including leading dollar signs, decimals, and trailing percentage signs and parentheses. So in this example

```
text = 'this is a string (0.7000) $0.9 80% 900000 0.9 chars not numbers.'
```

I would want my output to look like this

```
['this is a string', '(0.7000)', '$0.9', '80%', '900000', '0.9', 'chars not numbers.']
```

According to https://regex101.com/, this should work:

```
(\(?\$?[\.0-9,]+[.%)]?)
```

However, when I run this script on my string:

```
splitText = re.split(r'(\(?\$?[\.0-9,]+[.%)]?)', text)
print(splitText)
```

I get an empty list.

I have implemented this function successfully in other areas of my script, and so I am not sure why this one doesn't work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Sorry guys, I'm a bit sleep deprived and miswrote my own problem. I didn't want to split the words into characters, I wanted to maintain the words and only split the numbers. I've updated the output to its correct form.

Comment: Why don't you just use `text.split()`?

Comment: Can't your output be achieved by a simple `text.split()`?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe. When I run your code, i get this output (not your desired output) `['this is a string ', '(0.7000)', ' ', '$0.9', ' ', '80%', ' ', '900000', ' ', '0.9', ' chars not numbers', '.', '']`

Comment: `text.split()` doesn't separate the last dot

Comment: `re.split()` is normally used to specify the delimiters between the items with a regexp. The regexp shouldn't match the items themselves.

Comment: Maybe `re.findall()` is what you want.

Comment: This regex captures only numbers the way you described, filtering out anything else.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, miswrote the problem. I didn't want to split the words, I want to maintain each string of words and split the numbers only. I've updated my problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure your pattern is matching the right entities, all you need to add is a `filter(None, results)` to get rid of empty elements and add `\s*` around the pattern to "trim" out whitespace only chunks:

```
import re
text = 'this is a string (0.7000) $0.9 80% 900000 0.9 chars not numbers.'
print(filter(None, re.split(r"\s*(\(?\$?[0-9.,]+[.%)]?)\s*",text)))
# => ['this is a string', '(0.7000)', '$0.9', '80%', '900000', '0.9', 'chars not numbers', '.']
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/AKK0vV) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GFqO7n/3).

**Details**:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\(?\$?[0-9.,]+[.%)]?)` - Group 1:

  - `\(?` - an optional `(`
  - `\$?`  - an optional `$`
  - `[0-9.,]+` - 1+ digits, `.` or `,`
  - `[.%)]?` - an optional `.` or `%` symbols
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

Comment: Maybe a pattern like [`([^\w\s]*[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)?[^\w\s]*|[^\w\s])|\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/ItsemR/1) will be a bit more precise. If you need more help with this, please update the question.

Comment: I still get 'TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()'. But I also am braindead this morning and miswrote my own problem, so I've updated the description to what I'm correctly looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *`re.findall()`* to get better results, with whitespace trim
without the need for a lot of post processing gyrations.

`(?s)\s*((?:(?!\(?\$?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)[.%)]?).)+(?<!\s)|\(?\$?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)[.%)]?)\s*`

http://rextester.com/FKXM26376

Expanded

```
 (?s)
 \s* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           (?!
                \(? \$? 
                (?:
                     \d+ 
                     (?: \. \d* )?
                  |  \. \d+ 
                )
                [.%)]? 
           )
           . 
      )+
      (?<! \s )
   |  
      \(? \$? 
      (?:
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
      [.%)]? 
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s*
```

Python

```
import re

text = 'this is a string (0.7000)$0.9 80% 900000 0.9 chars not numbers.'

findText = re.findall(r'(?s)\s*((?:(?!\(?\$?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)[.%)]?).)+(?<!\s)|\(?\$?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)[.%)]?)\s*', text)

print(findText)
```

Output

```
['this is a string', '(0.7000)', '$0.9', '80%', '900000', '0.9', 'chars not numbers.']
```

Comment: wow, how the heck did you come up with such a massive regex? :)

Comment: I practice every day [175,000 word Dictionary regex](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt)

Comment: Actually I use a tool that does all this for me http://www.regexformat.com. I just _think_ about what I want to do, and press a button, then ... _wham_ , there it is ! I also have help from an extensive library of thousands of regexes I've written ..

Answer (score 0):

Running (python2)

```
import re
text = 'this is a string (0.7000) $0.9 80% 900000 0.9 chars not numbers.'
regex1 = r"(\(?\$?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*\%?\)?)"
st1 = re.split( regex1, text )
st2 = list( s.strip() for s in st1 if s.strip() != "" )
print st2
```

gives (edited to fit width)

```
['this is a string', '(0.7000)', '$0.9', '80%', '900000',
 '0.9', 'chars not numbers.']
```

Parts of the regex are (enclosed in parentheses so that they appear in the result)

- `\(?` optional opening parenthesis
- `\$?` optional dollar sign
- `[0-9]+` digits before decimal point (at least one)
- `\.?` optional decimal point
- `[0-9]*` optional digits after decimal point
- `\%?` optional percentage sign
- `\)?` optional closing parenthesis

After that, strip extra spaces and remove the empty strings to get your desired output.